# Is a finite group with a certain automorphism must be abelian

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $f:G \rightarrow G$ be an automorphism, such that $x f(x) f(f(x))=1$ for any $x \in G$. Is $G$ must be abelian?

I believe that there are examples where $G$ is not abelian, but I could not find any.

EDIT: I am interested in the case where $f$ has at most 3 fixed elements (including $1$).

Comment: To add a little context to Bananarama's and Alex J Best's answers, the existence of a nonabelian group of exponent $3$ (i.e., $x^3=1$ for all $x$) is an instance of [Burnside's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_problem).

Comment: I didn't know this, could you provide a link to that please? I can't find it in the wikipedia article you provided.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly an instance of Burnside's problem. I just think of Burnside's problem as "describe the group $B(m, n)$", as defined in Bounded Burnside Problem, rather than merely to determine whether or not it is finite. I don't think there's really any good reason for me thinking of it that way. The group of interest here would be $B(2, 3)$, or $B(n, 3)$ for $n$ arbitrary.

Comment: I saw the answers and I realized I forgot a condition (now added to the question): f has at most 3 fixed points, so f(x)=x would not be an example

Comment: You should probably post it as a different question, some people might not be enamoured by the fact you posted the wrong question and then took 8 days to realize it was the wrong question. Somehow making the efforts of the people who answered your question look useless.

Answer (score 1):

To search for a counter example, suppose we have a group $G$ such that the map $g \mapsto g^n$ is an isomorphism for some $n$. (When does this happen? Think about the kernel.)

If this is $f$, the condition you give is equivalent to the condition that the map $g \mapsto g^{n^2+n+1}$ is the identity. That is to say, that the order of any element of $G$ divides $n^2+n+1$.

So to find a counter example with this method, can you find a non-abelian group $G$ and natural number $n$ satisfying the above conditions?

Alternatively, you can start with the smallest non-abelian group, $D_6 (= \langle a,b:a^2=1=b^3, aba=b^{-1}\rangle)$ and try to find an automorphism that satisfies your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [Heisenberg group mod 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) with the trivial automorphism. it satisfies $x^3=1$ for all $x$ and is not abelian.

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer that the automotphism will have at most 3 fixed elements...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try to find an example using the simplest automorphism you can think of! ($x\mapsto x$)